# Slack not recognising Screen Recording permissions

Tags: permission, screen, slack

I have two users who are reporting that the Slack app continues to send them to the System Preferences→Security & Privacy→Privacy->Screen Recording list when they try and screen share.

They have confirmed that it is checked. They have restarted the Mac, and tried re-installing Slack. Nothing seems to work. I asked one to go in to the Slack Preferences→Audio & Video and run `Run an audio, video and screen sharing test` and usually it says Screen sharing is denied, occasionally it says it should work, but it doesn't when they try again.

Of course I cannot replicate the problem at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've had issues with similar settings in Privacy before. I've found that selecting the app then using the minus (-) to remove the app, then the plus (+) to add the app back often fixes it and makes it recognize.

Also, make sure there aren't multiple instances of the app running in Activity Viewer. If there are, force quit one of them and Slack should see the update.

Comment: I had to do an extended version of this answer to get it working (macOS Ventura 13.0). I uninstalled slack and deleted ~/Library/Application Support/Slack, clicked the (-) in Screen Recording list (which made it disappear completely), reinstalled Slack, manually added Slack (+) to the Screen Recording list (before opening Slack), opened Slack and tried a screen share, got the popup warning, went into the Screen Recording list and unchecked  Slack (blue toggle off), clicked "Later" to the pop up, then rechecked Slack (toggle on) and clicked "Quit and restart".

Comment: @shender, you should post that as a separate answer. Yours is the only solution that worked for me. (thanks!)

Answer (score 11):

I removed the app store version of Slack and downloaded it from the official [Slack website](https://slack.com/downloads/mac) instead, then it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked for me too, the accepted answer didn't. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me until I followed the _exact_ steps mentioned by @shender's comment on the other solution. It's super weird. I had already disabled and reenabled the permission countless times, but somehow that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried multiple solution but here sharing what have worked for me.

> Force quit slack application

> Go to Launchpad -> System preferences -> Security & privacy -> Screen Recording

> Click on the lock icon and select  Slack.

> Click (-) and again (+) to add the slack application.

> Go to Slack profile -> Preferences ->audio & video -> Run test

-- Your screen share test will pass --

Comment: Aren't only steps 1 and 4 needed and if so then how does this differ from @beervenger`s answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343479)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).